# Double relation to one table merged as one

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I will try simplify my example. I've got a table called `friendship` with two relations to `user` (lets call them `user1` and `user2`). I would like to retrieve an alphabetical list of my friends. I can appear in the `user1` or in the `user2`. The only way I can know is by using unions:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM
    (SELECT "user1"."name" AS "name"
    FROM "friendship" AS "friendship" LEFT JOIN "user" AS "user1"
    ON "friendship"."user1_id" = "requestedUser"."id" 
    AND "user1"."id" != 'me'
    WHERE ("friendship"."user2_id" = 'me')

    UNION

    SELECT "user2"."name" AS "name"
    FROM "friendship" AS "friendship"
        LEFT JOIN "user" AS "user2" 
        ON "friendship"."user2_id" = "user2"."id" 
        AND "user2"."id" != 'me'
    WHERE ("friendship"."user1_id" = 'me')
    ) AS f
ORDER BY "name"
LIMIT ?;
```

Is there any easier way? Or maybe there is possibility to do it in single SELECT? Do you know how do it in `sequelize`?

Answer (score 0):

in Sequelize you should be able to do `user.getFriends()` to get all of a users friends.  If you aliased the associations to something like `outbound` and `inbound` it would be `user.getInbound()` and `user.getOutbound()`.

Sequelize automatically creates and names methods on instances that allow you to get associated models.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know, but it doesn't solve my problem that I want sort friends by same field in two associations.